# Best way to create hundreds of UIImage at start and have them available from any where in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimage

I have about 120 images in xcassets that I would like to create using UIImage (or something else if you have a better way) when I start my app and have them available from anywhere in my app as they won't change and I might need them many times.

I was thinking to create them in viewDidLoad of my main view but how do I get them available to any view controller without creating a struc then a static variable? Is that possible?

What is the best practice there?

Thanks for your help.

***UPDATE***:

The thing is that I have a view that allows the user to pick a list of countries. Each country is represented by a label and an image (the flag, which is less than 10KB). And this view might be accessed many times during the life cycle of the app. That's why I wanted to store them somewhere while I'm creating the UIImages so that I don't have to create them again everytime I go into that view. But indeed, I should create them not at the start of the app but once my view is loaded for the first time.

Comment: On mobile devices like the iPhone/iPad (which have relatively limited hardware capabilities), it is not recommended to initialize all of the app resources in advance; instead, it is best to do 'lazy initialization' and e.g. load your images only **if** and **when** they are needed. Especially if it is as many as 120 images.

Comment: Regarding making them available from anywhere in your app, if you use the system provided loading mechanism then there's nothing special to do: just call (e.g.) `-[UIImage imageNamed:]` from the relevant location. If you still want to "preload" all your images and keep them cached, you could use a singleton object and name it `ImageManager` or something similar. In any case, you should balance the little speed you gain by not having to load the images on demand vs. the memory pressure you put on the app all along.

Comment: I agree with Nicolas re lazy loading. But how big are these images? How frequently are you reusing them? If large, I'd actually advise against `imageNamed` (because that's caching them, which is an extravagant use of memory and can eventually lead to problems). If your images are tiny (e.g. emoticons), then it's somewhat academic. But large/many images can lead to memory problems if you're not careful.

Comment: @NicolasMiari you should answer the question with those two comments; they're good enough.

Comment: @jrhurton not sure I answered **his question** (especially with the first comment), but there it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mobile devices like the iPhone/iPad (which have relatively limited hardware capabilities), it is not recommended to initialize all of the app resources in advance; instead, it is best to do 'lazy initialization' and e.g. load your images only **if** and **when** they are needed. Especially if it is as many as 120 images (This is not just my opinion, but a "best practice" suggested by Apple themselves, and adhered to by most iOS developers).

Regarding making them available from anywhere in your app, if you use the system provided loading mechanism and the lazy initialization policy described above, then there's nothing special to do: just call (e.g.) `-[UIImage imageNamed:]` (in your case, the swift equivalent) from the relevant location.

If -instead- you still want to "preload" all your images early on and keep them cached, you could use a singleton object and name its class  `ImageManager` or something similar.

In any case, you should balance the little speed you gain by not having to load the images on demand vs. the memory pressure you put on the app all along.

Of course, if each image is very small (as @Rob suggested), you can get away with it in terms of memory usage.

EDIT - 
Find the locations of your code where the images are actually needed (for display purposes, or otherwise), and insert there the method calls to load those images. See the example below (sorry it is in Objective-C, not swift):

```
// Example
// Custom UIViewController subclass that controls one of your app's screens
// where an image is needed.

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /* Lazy initialization: load image just before it is needed, 
       not earlier.
     */
    UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage"];
    // Note: imageNamed: caches the images it loads. If you call it
    // again later with the same image name, and it is still in memory, 
    // it will use that instance instead of loading the file again from
    // disk.

    UIImageView* myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];

    [self.view addSubview: myImageView];

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just few questions. How would you implement this lazy loading mechanism? Just add lazy in front of my function? I updated my question for more precision

Comment: No, "lazy" refers to the policy, it's not an actual feature of the programming language. Just use the functions provided by iOS/UIKit for loading images in the parts of your code where the image is needed for display (for example, the `viewDidLoad` method of the corresponding view controller).

Comment: Ok. But is it worth it to make a singleton that will first be called in the viewdidload?

Comment: No, you only need a singleton if you are going to preload your images. If you are going the "lazy" route, you don't need any image managers (see edits to my answer).

Comment: If you use a singleton, tipically you provide a class (static) method to get a reference to the unique instance, and the instance is created the first time it is called (also, lazily). If you want to preload all images in advance, you should ensure that by instantiating your singleton/manager right after app launch (e.g. `-applicationd:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`), and before you present any screen of your app.

Comment: Hmm I didn't pay attention that with the method I was using (same than the one you used) the images were cached, so in that case indeed, no need for a singleton. Thanks a lot.